# Update vuex state after axios PUT response

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, vuex

I am trying to get a grip on Vuex by developing a small Games List app with a small NodeJS backend.

I have a Game List component with an option to update a game's completed status with a button

```
<template>
  <div id="gameList">
    <div v-for="game in allGames" :key="game._id" class="game">
      <strong>{{ game.name }}</strong>
      <em class="completed">{{ game.completed }}</em>
      <button @click="updateCompleted(game._id)" v-if="game.completed === false">Set completed</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { mapGetters, mapActions } from "vuex";

export default {
  name: "GameList",
  methods: {
    ...mapActions(["getGames", "updateCompleted"])
  },
  computed: mapGetters(["allGames"]),
  created() {
    this.getGames();
  }
};
</script>
```

And my Store

```
const state = {
  gamelist: []
};

const getters = {
  allGames: state => state.gamelist
};

const actions = {
  getGames: async context => {
    const response = await axios.get("http://localhost:8081/allgames");
    context.commit("setGames", response.data);
  },

  updateCompleted: async (context, payload) => {

    const response = await axios.put(
      `http://localhost:8081/update/${payload}`, {
        completed: true
      }
    );

    context.commit('updateCompleted', response)
  }
};

const mutations = {
  setGames: (state, payload) => (state.gamelist = payload),

  updateCompleted: state => console.log(state)
};

export default {
  state,
  getters,
  actions,
  mutations
};
```

The getter works perfectly and so does the action, but I can't seem to figure out how to mutate the state ( the gamelist ) after the PUT response so that I can update the view and display the game's new completed status without doing a refresh. The PUT response is just a "success" message, when the game in the database has been updated.

The GET response in the getGames action looks like this:

```
[{"completed":true,"_id":"5e0df1af63680526c07c670c","name":"Alien Isolation"},{"completed":false,"_id":"5e0df75ea252fe27e58577f6","name":"Red Dead Redemption"}]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change these as follows:

```
context.commit('updateCompleted', {response, payload});
```

```
updateCompleted: (state, data) => {
  if(data.response.status === 200){
    let game = state.gamelist.findIndex(game => game._id === data.payload);
    state.gamelist[game].completed = true;
  }
}
```

Comment: Or alternatively, if your allgames query is light, you can add `context.dispatch('getGames')`after your commit to refetch the whole data set.

Comment: Nice! That works perfectly! Where would you place the dispatch function the refetch the data ?

Comment: Inside the updateCompleted action, after the axios call.